# Open Source FIX Client Simulator

Tags: c++, python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I want test a FIX gateway for our company and was wondering if anything in opensource already exists that I can use or perhaps leverage to complete this task.

I am currently looking at QuickFix but I am not sure if it has a client that can be used against any standard FIX gateway.

Also links to any learning material that exist on this topic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**QuickFIXengine code comes with couple of examples, see [examples](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/tree/master/examples)**

You probably want `tradeclient` for sending messages. It is a command line tool that will send FIX messages to server.

You can use the `ordermatch` example to start up simple FIX server which will cross orders and send ExecutionReports back to your client.

For all example applications you need to provide a config file to startup up. Just follow the instructions at `quickfixengine` web site, see [example config file](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html). Your client will be `initiator` and server `acceptor`.

I've been using those example apps heavily for testing especially the `ordermatcher`, I've updated mine to handle amend orders and separates stock/futures/options symbols and so on.

The `tradeclient` uses screen logger so you should see all the outgoing and incoming messages on the command line.

Comment: Link no longer works

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative GUI tool that allows to simulate both client and server. It is called [MINI FIX](https://elato.se/minifix/doc.html). One can construct messages as he/she sees or use code to talk to it and get respective response. The only downside is that it is Windows only.

Answer (score 3):

QuickFIX can be used to send standard-compliant messages (with different safety-levels//use strong safety:-) to FIX servers/gateways.

quickfix has nice sample code on its site: http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/sending_messages.html

Comment: I am trying with QuickFix, I am trying to see if I can find some sample FIx encoded messages somewhere

Comment: quickfix has nice sample code on its site: http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/sending_messages.html